# Discrepancy in reputation viewed in Summary and Reputation tabs

Tags: support

When I view the Summary tab in my profile, it is showing **`+55`** reputation points for this answer: https://superuser.com/a/590146

When I view the same answer in the Reputation tab in my profile, or if I view the actual answer, it is showing **`+75`** reputation points for this answer.

I have refreshed my browser for the pages many times with no change. Is this just a case of the summary information not being updated as often as the other pages?

---

Here are some screenshots:

**Summary Tab of profile page**:

[image: Summary Tab of profile page]

**Reputation Tab of profile page**:

[image: Reputation Tab of profile page]

---

Here is a partial of output from https://superuser.com/reputation:

```
...
...

 2    589054 (10)
 1    589054 (15)
-- 2013-04-29 rep +25   = 1071 
 2    590146 (10)
 2    590146 (10)
 2    590154 (10)
 2    590146 (10)
 2    590146 (10)
 1    590146 (15)
 2    590146 (10)
 2    590146 (10)
 16   590114 (2)
 2    590175 (10)
-- 2013-05-01 rep +97   = 1168  

** rep today: 97
** rep this week (2013-04-28 - 2013-05-04): 122
** rep this month (2013-05-01 - 2013-05-31): 97

...
...
```

Let me know if I should post the full output.

Comment: Could you provide the output of `http://superuser.com/reputation` for today?

Comment: I checked your profile: My guess is that two up votes (worth 20) were cast before an up vote to the last post in the list, and the other 4 afterwards. *Summary* shows the most recent reputation events, collapsing some. It doesn't show e.g. *today's* chances, as the reputation list does.

Comment: Also, if you're reporting a possible bug, it helps to provide screenshots or a full explanation of what you're seeing exactly, especially for something that's *very* time dependent, such as this issue...

Comment: @DanielBeck - I have added some screenshots. I suspect the issue is as you have described in your second comment regarding some events being collapsed on the summary page, rather than a bug. If you feel it's appropriate, I'll remove the **`[Bug]`** tag.

Comment: Still, today's data from `/reputation` would be interesting, as it's chronological AFAIK.

Comment: @DanielBeck - I added the output of http://superuser.com/reputation for today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *summary* tab does not show all of today's reputation changes. It's the *most recent* changes, which sometimes are less, sometimes more than one day's. Both views (*summary* and *reputation*) do collapse reputation changes to the same posts (and in the latter case, changes of the same kind) into one list entry, and the summary seems to be limited to four entries.

As you can see from `/reputation` and the expanded reputation changes per post, you first received two up votes for 590146 (14:48, 14:55), then one up vote for 590154 (15:02), and then another four up votes (15:06, :08, :12, :16) and one accept (15:12) for 590146. The summary page simply used the up vote for 590154 as the cut-off point so that the 20 reputation you got earlier didn't make it into the summary.